# Tokenizing source code in Java

Tags: java, tokenize

For a systems software development course, I'm working on a complete assembler for an instructor-invented assembly language. Currently I'm working on the tokenizer. While doing some searching, I've come across the Java `StringTokenizer` class...but I see that it has been essentially deprecated. It seems far easier to use, however, than the `String.split` method with regular expressions.

Is there some reason that I should avoid using it? Is there perhaps something else within the typical Java libraries that would suit this task well that I am not aware of?

EDIT: Giving more detail.

The reason I am considering `String.split` complicated is that my knowledge of regular expressions is roughly that I know of them. While it would be helpful for my general knowledge as a software developer to know them, I'm not sure that I want to invest the time right now, especially if there is an easier alternative present.

In terms of my usage of the tokenizer: it will go through a text file containing assembly code and break it into tokens, passing the text and token type to a parser. Delimiters include white space (spaces, tabs, newlines), the comment-start character '|' (which can occur on its own line, or after other text), and the comma to separate operands in an instruction.

I would write that more mathematically, but my knowledge of formal languages is a bit rusty.

EDIT 2: Asking question more clearly

I have seen the documentation on the StringTokenizer class. It would have suited my purposes well, but its use is discouraged. Other than `String.split`, is there something within the standard java libraries that would be helpful?

Comment: Could you explain how you're going to tokenize your input string/source? Changes are that there are better ways to do this than both `StringTokenizer` and `split(...)` could do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't fear the regex, get yourself a regex editor such as the following eclipse plugin,
http://brosinski.com/regex/update and you'll be able to test the expressions without compiling or even before writing your program.

If you need more reference, here are some very useful sites :

- http://www.regular-expressions.info/
- http://regexlib.com/

Although I think the suggestion above of using JavaCC sound like the right approach.
Another option would be [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/).

Heres a post comparing the experience of [ANTLR vs JavaCC](http://beust.com/weblog2/archives/000145.html).

Comment: I second this.  It won't take you more than 30 minutes to learn enough about regex to effectively use String.split or Scanner.  For a programmer learning to write basic regexes is easy and takes very little time.  Becoming a master will take you the rest of your career.

Comment: Although I do still chuckle at the 1997 quote from Jamie Zawinski one of the founders of Netscape and Mozilla.org "Some people, when confronted with a problem, think 'I know, I'll use regular expressions.' Now they have two problems."

Comment: That quote is a favorite of mine as well.

Answer (score 3):

I believe that the java.util.Scanner class has replaced StringTokenizer.  Scanner let's you handle tokens one at a time, whereas String.split() will split the entire string (which could be large, if you're parsing a source code file).  Using Scanner, you can examine each token, decide what action to take, then discard that token.

Comment: Generally, you shouldn't be parsing an entire source file at once, but a single source line at a time. It's easier on memory, and it makes it easier to keep track of line numbers for issuing error messages.

Answer (score 3):

If what you're building is an assembler, I would use [JavaCC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaCC) for building the parser/compiler.

Comment: This would have been an extremely helpful tool, but we were explicitly forbidden to use tools like this. Thank you, though - this is pretty cool!

Answer (score 2):

From the documentation:

StringTokenizer is a legacy class that is retained for compatibility reasons although its use is discouraged in new code. It is recommended that anyone seeking this functionality use the split  method of String or the java.util.regex package instead.

The following example illustrates how the String.split method can be used to break up a string into its basic tokens:

```
     String[] result = "this is a test".split("\\s");
     for (int x=0; x<result.length; x++)
         System.out.println(result[x]);
```

prints the following output:

```
     this
     is
     a
     test
```

Comment: Right, I came across this as well. It would have been good if I noted that more clearly, but this is what I was referring to when I said "essentially deprecated".

Answer (score 0):

Something is deprecated when there is a better alternative, or those methods are dangerous in some situations. So the answer is - Yep, you can use it, but there is a better way to achieve what you need.

Btw, what is complicate about split?